# Updating the location of a jframe component with a timer

Tags: java, swing, jframe, mouseevent, jlabel

I'm trying to make a program that uses a label to chase the user's mouse, and I have two problems:

First, the location of the label is judged by the entire computer screen's coordinates rather than just the window.

Second, the label doesn't move during the application when the timer uses `repaint()`.

```
private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                MouseFollowDisplay frame = new MouseFollowDisplay();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public MouseFollowDisplay() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    final JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("RUN!");
    lblNewLabel.setRequestFocusEnabled(false);
    lblNewLabel.setLocation(new Point(5, 5));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 11, 31, 23);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    contentPane.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        int DELAY = 500;

        ActionListener MouseDetect = new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                PointerInfo a = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
                Point b = a.getLocation();
                int x = (int) b.getX();
                int y = (int) b.getY();
                System.out.println(x + "," + y); 

                int lx = lblNewLabel.getX();
                int ly = lblNewLabel.getY();

                if (lx <= x+5 && lx >= x-5 && ly <= y+5 && ly >= y-5){
                    DetectMouse.stop();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You Lose!");
                }else{
                    lx = -((lx - x) * 5) / (Math.abs(lx - x));
                    ly = -((ly - y) * 5) / (Math.abs(ly - y));
                    lblNewLabel.repaint(lx, ly, 31, 23);
                }

                if (DELAY >= 150) {
                    DELAY -= 5;
                    DetectMouse.setDelay(DELAY);
                }
            }
        };

        Timer DetectMouse = new Timer(DELAY, MouseDetect);

        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
            if (DetectMouse.isRunning()){
                DetectMouse.stop();
                DELAY = 500;
            }
            else{
                DetectMouse.start();    
            }
        }   
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The

```
lblNewLabel.repaint(lx, ly, 31, 23)
```

call does not move your label. See the javadoc of that repaint method

> Adds the specified region to the dirty region list if the component is showing. The component will be repainted after all of the currently pending events have been dispatched.

What you have to do is adjust the location of your label, and repaint the panel (both the old region of the label and the new region).

A better approach then the `null` layout is having your own `JComponent` or `JPanel` where you override the `paintComponent` method and paint that string using the `Graphics#drawString` method. In this case, do not forget to call `super.paintComponent` to avoid having the text appearing multiple times (see for example [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10459391/image-not-repainting-just-multiplying/) for a description of what happens if you forget to call `super.paintComponent`)

Comment: How would I do that? Is there a way to make it repaint the label at the moment the Location is set?